# UK visa error in cover letter

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

I need your advice. I made an error in my UK visa application. I already submitted my documents in the VAC and when I got home I noticed that I indicated GBP42/1 Thai baht instead of GBP1/42 Thai baht in my cover letter as the conversion rate that I used. Is there any way that I can correct this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you use the correct conversion rate when calculating the conversions?  If so I would not worry too much.

Answer (score 1):

What you referenced in your cover letter, the transposition of numbers in the conversion rate, is unlikely to have an adverse affect. A cover letter is not evidentiary, just a summary of what is contained in the accompanying packet. Hopefully, the lower rate was not part of your calculation in the application, itself. Even so, an Entry Clearance Officer would verify your figures using the [Oanda rate of exchange](https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/) against the original figures.